# Kotlin Job.join()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Coroutines,want to know that `join()` function can block the main thread for the job completion or not.Also i have written programme to know the same.

```
fun main(){ 
  printData() 
} 
fun printData() = runBlocking { val job = GlobalScope.launch { delay(4000) println("One from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}") } 
   job.join() 
   println("Two from thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}") 
}
```

Why the last println i.e.Two from thread.. prints after the println from `job`. Does `job.join()` blocks its execution? Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: `job.join()` suspends the current coroutine until the job is complete.

Comment: @marstran if the job.join() suspends the current coroutine then why last println not called earlier which is run on main thread?

Comment: Because you suspend (pausing) the coroutine on the previous line. You suspend the execution of the coroutine on the main thread until the job is complete.